# How to unselect Excel row using keyboard

Tags: excel

When an excel row is selected and we ctrl+click it, the row is not unselected.
Is there a way to unselect a particular row using the keyboard ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, it's not possible.

All I can do is direct you to [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/UnSelect.aspx)'s site, which has macros that can unselect cells/areas

Code supplied here too:

### UnSelectActiveCell

This procedure will remove the Active Cell from the Selection.

```
Sub UnSelectActiveCell()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim RR As Range
    For Each R In Selection.Cells
        If StrComp(R.Address, ActiveCell.Address, vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
            If RR Is Nothing Then
                Set RR = R
            Else
                Set RR = Application.Union(RR, R)
            End If
        End If
    Next R
    If Not RR Is Nothing Then
        RR.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

### UnSelectCurrentArea

This procedure will remove the Area containing the Active Cell from the Selection.

```
Sub UnSelectCurrentArea()
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim RR As Range

    For Each Area In Selection.Areas
        If Application.Intersect(Area, ActiveCell) Is Nothing Then
            If RR Is Nothing Then
                Set RR = Area
            Else
                Set RR = Application.Union(RR, Area)
            End If
        End If
    Next Area
    If Not RR Is Nothing Then
        RR.Select
    End If
End Sub
```